# How to resize images according to screen size?

Tags: android, layout

I have made an app that shows 6 images, 3 per row. It looks perfect in the layout designer of android studio but not on physical device that has an other screen resolution. I wasn't surprised about that but I don't know how to make the app compatible to all screen sizes.

**Layout designer Android Studio:**(1:4) 
[image]

**Physical Device:**(1:2)
[image]

**Source code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.testing.app.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image1"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image3"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Image1"
    android:contentDescription="Image2"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image4"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image5"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Image6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Image2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Image2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/Image3"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image6"
    android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Linear Layout and set equal weights for all three images in a row.

Look at this code, I have trimmed it a bit, but the main parts are:

Changed RelativeLayout to LinearLayout (with 'horizontal' orientation), then changed the width of all three images to 0dp - **android:layout:width="0dp"**, and added equal weight **layout_weight = "1"** for all three of them'

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="Image3"
        android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="Image2"
        android:src="@drawable/_5221802" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This would work on any device of any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need not have to run the app to see how your app's layout will look on particular device, you can check that in Eclipse - layout editor. There are many dropdowns at the top bar for you to select the type of device where you want your app to run and find out, how it will look there.

To answer your question, ideally, you should define Gridview and add your images there.